# UIView position detect

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

How can I detect if my UIView frame is equal to myFrame?

I need something like:

```
CGRect myFrame;
myFrame = CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50);
if(view.frame == myFrame) 
{
    NSLog(@"Congrats");
}
```

Comment: You can use `CGRectContainsRect`, if you are checking if first one is inside second one. For equality it is `CGRectEqualToRect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, -51, 320, 50);
if (CGRectEqualToRect(myFrame,view.frame))
{
    NSLog(@"Congrats");
}
```

See the apple docs on CGGeometry Reference for more info: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html.

Comment: Though, you might want to use some fuzz, not exact equality, if the user is involved.

Answer (score 0):

CGRectEquatToRect is a function which checks the equality of two frames, just needs to pass the frames of two views whose equality you want to check. It returns the boolean result. Returns true, if two frames are equal else false.